# Element is Not clickable at point(215, 251) error

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I have a non-angular app where I click a link and a new popup modal appears.  I then can select to upload a picture or video.  I tell protractor and/or webdriver to click on the upload photos button.

If I use:

```
var addPhotos = element(by.css('#px-select-photo')).click();
```

I can visually see the button being pressed down however the test is then failed and the error not clickable at...(215, 251)

So then I thought I could trick it into clicking x y position (which I'm assuming those two numbers in the error are) and I get nothing

Code I used for that is:

```
browser.actions().mouseMove({
  x: 702,
  y: 621
}).click().perform();
```

It clicks, but not on the button.

Lastly I tried this:

```
var addPhotos = element(by.css('#px-select-photo'));
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', addPhotos.getWebElement());
browser.actions().mouseMove(addPhotos).click().perform();
```

Which also yields no results.

Also, I am receiving this warning:

> WARNING - more than one element found for locator `By.cssSelector("#px-select-photo")` - the first result will be used

However, there is only one element in the html file, don't know what thats all about either.

Comment: Don't lose your mind. Let's first understand what is that warning about. How about you make your selector more specific - say `#pxupload3 input#px-select-photo`? Does it make any difference?

Comment: @alecxe Just tried I am getting no element found error for #pxupload3

Comment: browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', addPhotos.getWebElement());
browser.actions().mouseMove(addPhotos).click().perform();

Comment: That did it @Shubham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below code:-

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].click()', addPhotos.getWebElement()); 
browser.actions().mouseMove(addPhotos).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

The warning might be the key to solving the problem.

Make your selector *more specific* and *wait for the upload button to become clickable*:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var addPhotos = element(by.css('#pxupload3 input#px-select-photo'));

browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(addPhotos), 5000);
addPhotos.click();
```

Alternative option would be to get all elements by `px-select-photo` id and filter visible:

```
var addPhotos = element.all(by.css("#px-select-photo")).filter(function (addButton) {
    return addButton.isDisplayed();
}).first();
addPhotos.click();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with this method.  What do I define EC as?

Comment: @NicolePhillips okay. Is this a public site and you can share a link? (or share a complete html of the page) Thanks.

Comment: it is not unfortunately I will add the entire html

Comment: @NicolePhillips added an alternative option.

Comment: So I tried that function got error: Index out of bound. Trying to access element at index: 0, but there are only 0 elements that match locator By.cssSelector("#px-select-photo") so I got curious and did a count which state there were two elements, so I switched it to get(1) still nothing.